# Using Date.Now in SQL Function

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, function

I have a `Function` like this;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fngcodeme]
(
    @HESAP INT, @DOV INT, @TEKLIF VARCHAR(10), @BAS datetime, @BIT datetime
)
RETURNS FLOAT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result FLOAT

IF CONVERT(DATETIME, @BIT,103) <= '20110228'
    SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(TUTAR)
        FROM YAZ..MARDATA.M_HAREKET
        WHERE TEMEL_HESAP = @HESAP
        AND DOVIZ_KOD = @DOV
        AND REF_KOD = 'GC'
        AND BACAK_GRUP = 'PERT'
        AND ISL_KOD = 1
        AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '%' + @TEKLIF + '%'
        AND ISL_TAR >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @BAS,103)
        AND ISL_TAR <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @BIT,103)
        )
ELSE
    SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(TUTAR)
        FROM YAZ..MARDATA.M_GHAREKET
        WHERE TEMEL_HESAP = @HESAP
        AND DOVIZ_KOD = @DOV
        AND REF_KOD = 'GC'
        AND BACAK_GRUP = 'PERT'
        AND ISL_KOD = 1
        AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '%' + @TEKLIF + '%'
        AND ISL_TAR >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @BAS,103)
        AND ISL_TAR <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @BIT,103)
        )

RETURN @Result

END
```

`M_GHAREKET` table is my monthly data table. Every end of the month this table load to `M_HAREKET`. (And deleted all data in `M_GHAREKET`)

`M_HAREKET` is a Big Bucket. `M_GHAREKET` is small. (I mean `M_HAREKET` has now over 500.000 data, `M_GHAREKET` over 4.000)

What i want is for this `Function`, IF @BAS date's month value is equal `DateTime.Now.Month` value i want use `M_GHAREKET` table, else use `M_HAREKET` table.

How should i change this function like that?

Is it possible like this IF clause with `DateTime.Now.Month` in `SQL Function`?

Or i should use in my `ASP.NET` page? How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) and [year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx).

```
declare @BAS datetime
set @BAS = '2011-03-15'

if month(getdate()) = month(@BAS) and
   year(getdate()) = year(@BAS)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEDIFF` to find the difference between two date in months. This returns the number of time period boundaries crossed so when checking for months it would only return 0 if the two dates are in the same calendar year and month

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME
SET @date1 = '2011-03-01'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MM, @date1, '2011-02-28') -- -1
SELECT DATEDIFF(MM, @date1, '2011-03-20') -- 0
SELECT DATEDIFF(MM, @date1, '2010-03-01') -- -12
```

So to check that a date is in the same month and year as today (`GETDATE()`) you could use

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME
SET @date1 = '2011-03-01'

IF DATEDIFF(MM, @date1, GETDATE()) = 0
  BEGIN
    -- Do your work
  END
```